# React Native Warning: "React.jsx: type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm encountering a "React Native Warning: 'React.jsx: type is invalid'" when attempting to use custom fonts in my React Native application.

I've tried several approaches to solve the problem, including checking for any issues with importing/exporting components, verifying the font file location, and ensuring that my navigation setup is correct. However, I'm still facing this issue.

Is there something I'm missing in my code setup or configuration? Any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated.

App.js code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo'; 
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { HomePage } from './screens/HomePage';
import  SignInPage  from './screens/SignInPage';
import  RegisterPage  from './screens/RegisterPage';



const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const getFonts = () => Font.loadAsync( {
   'DM-Serif-Display' : require('./assets/fonts/DM Serif Display Regular.ttf')
  });


export default function App() {
  
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return (
     <SignInPage />
    );
  } else {
    <AppLoading
    startAsync={getFonts}
    onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)}
    />
  }

  return (

   <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SignIn" screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInPage}></Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen name='Register' component={RegisterPage}></Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomePage" component={HomePage}></Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>

   </NavigationContainer>
  );
  }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }, 
});
```

HomePage.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';


export function HomePage() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.purpleView}>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput style={styles.myTextInputnput} placeholder='enter text here' placeholderTextColor={'black'} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.firstHeader}>Upptäck de bästa salongerna</Text>
      <Text style={styles.headerLocation}>Stockholm, Sweden</Text>
      <Text style={styles.txtVisits}>Senaste besökta</Text>

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  purpleView: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 94,
    backgroundColor: '#9A3DBA', 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    margin: 10,
    left: -35

  }, myTextInput: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '200',
    left: 35,
    textAlign: 'center'
    
  }, inputView: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    margin: 20,
    borderRadius: 15,
    height: '45%',
    left: -22

  }, headerLocation: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'black',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    left: -80,
    top: 35

  }, firstHeader: {
    left: -50,
    top: 15
  }
  
});
```

RegisterPage.js code:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

export default function RegisterPage() {

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const navigateToHomePage = () => {
        navigation.navigate('HomePage');
    }

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}> 
        <Text style={styles.headerName}>Namn*</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.nameInput}/>
        <Text style={styles.headerNumber}>Mobilnummer*</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.numberInput}/>
        <Text style={styles.headerMail}>E-post*</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.mailInput}/>
        <Text style={styles.headerPassword}>Lösenord*</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.passwordInput}/>
        <Text style={styles.showPasswordHeader}>Visa lösenord</Text>
        <View style={styles.mySquare}/>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.createAccountButton} onPress={navigateToHomePage}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Fortsätt</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
  
    }, headerName: {
        fontSize: 18,
        top: -300,
        left: -120

    }, nameInput: {
        width: 300,
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 12,
        backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9',
        top: -290,
        borderColor: 'transparent'

    }, headerNumber: {
        fontSize: 18,
        top: -270,
        left: -90

    }, numberInput: {
        width: 300,
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 12,
        backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9',
        top: -260,
        borderColor: 'transparent'

    }, headerMail: {
        fontSize: 18,
        top: -240,
        left: -115

    }, mailInput: {
        width: 300,
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 12,
        backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9',
        top: -235,
        borderColor: 'transparent'

    }, headerPassword: {
        fontSize: 18,
        top: -200,
        left: -105

    }, passwordInput: {
        width: 300,
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 12,
        backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9',
        top: -190,
        borderColor: 'transparent'

    }, mySquare: {
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9',
        left: -140,
        borderRadius: 3,
        top: -190

    }, showPasswordHeader: {
        top: -170,
        left: -65

    }, createAccountButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#9A3DBA',
        width: 256,
        height: 49,
        borderRadius: 12,
        top: -90

    }, buttonText: {
        color: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center',
        top: 12,
        fontSize: 18
    }

})
```

SignInPage.js code:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';


export default function SignInPage() {

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const goToRegister = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Register')
}
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <Image source={require('../assets/icons/secondIcon.png')}
        style={styles.myImage} />
        <Text style={styles.companyHeader}>SweBarbers</Text>
        <Text style={styles.usernameHeader}>Epost/Mobilnummer</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.usernameInput} />
        <Text style={styles.passwordHeader}>Lösenord</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.passwordInput}/>
        <Text style={styles.forgottenPassword}>Glömt Lösenord?</Text>
        <Text style={styles.showPasswordHeader}>Visa lösenord</Text>
        <View style={styles.mySquare}/>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Logga in</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.orContainer}>
        <View style={styles.line} />
        <Text style={styles.orText}>Eller</Text>
        <View style={styles.line} />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.registerButton} onPress={goToRegister}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Skapa konto</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',

    }, companyHeader: {
        color: '#9A3DBA',
        fontSize: 36,
        fontWeight: '400',
        top: -170,
        left: 85,
        fontFamily: 'DM Serif Display Regular'

    }, usernameHeader: {
        fontSize: 18,
        top: -120,
        left: -65,
        fontWeight: '500'

    }, usernameInput: {
       width: 300,
       height: 40,
       borderWidth: 1,
       borderRadius: 15,
       top: -115,
       backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9',
       borderColor: 'transparent'
       
    }, passwordHeader: {
        fontSize: 18,
        left: -105,
        top: -90,
        fontWeight: '500'

    }, passwordInput: {
       width: 300,
       height: 40,
       borderWidth: 1,
       borderRadius: 12,
       backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9',
       top: -85,
       borderColor: 'transparent'

    }, forgottenPassword: {
        top: -74,
        left: -90,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '400'

    }, showPasswordHeader: {
        top: -60,
        left: -75,
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: '400'

    }, mySquare: {
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9',
        left: -140,
        borderRadius: 3,
        top: -80
     
    }, loginButton: {
      backgroundColor: '#9A3DBA',
      width: 114,
      height: 48,
      borderRadius: 12,
      top: -10
      

    }, buttonText: {
      color: 'white',
      textAlign: 'center',
      top: 15,
      fontWeight: '600',
      fontSize: 20

    }, registerButton: {
      backgroundColor: '#9A3DBA',
      width: 256,
      height: 49,
      borderRadius: 12,
      top: 30

    }, orContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginTop: 80,
      top: -20

    }, line: {
      flex: 1,
      height: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'black', 
      marginHorizontal: 11,

    }, orText: {
      fontWeight: '500'

    }, myImage: {
      top: -90,
      left: -100
    }
    });
```